# Undefined reference to 'function' in c whilst the function is already defined

Tags: c, gcc, gnu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int arithmetic();
int two_variable();
int three_variable();
int quadratic();
int trigonometric();

//declaring all the main functions
int main(void){
    char j;
    int select;
    printf("Enter mode\n 1. Arithmetic \t 2.Trigonometric \n 3.Quadratic\t 4.Two Variable\n \t 5.Three Variable \n");
    scanf("%d",&select);
    switch(select){
        case 1: ; arithmetic(); break;
        case 2: ; trigonometric();break;
        case 3: ; quadratic(); break;
        case 4: ; two_variable();break;
        case 5: ; three_variable();break;
    default: printf("ERROR");
        }
    printf("Continue? y/n");
    scanf("%c",j);
    if(j == 'y'){
        int main();
    }

return 0;

}

int arithmetic(){ 
     int temp1,i,a,n,c = 0; //c is for count the no. of times function was called 
     float num[n]; 
    float ans = 0;
    printf("enter number of inputs:\0.2t");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("enter numbers");
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
        scanf("%f",&num[i]);
    }
    printf(" 1.+ \t 2.- \n 3.* \t 4./t /n 5.^ /t 6.log ");
    scanf("%d",a);
    switch(a){
    case 1://addition
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
          ans += num[i];
            }
            break;
    case 2://subtraction
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            ans -= num[i];
        }
            break;
    case 3://multiplication
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            ans = 1;
            ans *= num[i];
        }
            break;
    case 4://division
        ans = 1;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        ans = ans/num[i];
        }
            break;
    case 5: //power
        ans = pow(num[0],num[1]);
        break;
    case 6 : //log
        if(c>1){
        ans = log(temp1); }
        else{
        ans = log(num[0]);  }
        break;
    default :printf("ERROR");
    }
    temp1 == ans;
    printf("ans = %f",ans);
    char j;
    printf("Continue? y/n");
    scanf("%c",j);
    if(j == 'y'){
        int arithmetic();
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ohh.. please fix the syntax.

Comment: Your code implement only one of the 5 functions defined and called by `main`. Where are `int two_variable(){}`
`int three_variable(){}`
`int quadratic(){}`
`int trigonometric(){}` ?

Comment: Please try to create a [***Minimal***, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And  please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And include the actual errors you get, in full, complete and unedited.

Answer (score 1):

you are using below functions in your program

```
arithmetic();
trigonometric();
quadratic(); 
two_variable();
three_variable()
```

But you have implemented just arithmetic() function not the other ones. Implement those and error will go away.